# Can't load local images with HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I am developing a simple site with Django, and wanted to load some images locally to some pages. But it doesn't load for some reason. I know there are similar questions, and from what I understand;

**a-)** It can be a directory problem, html file and img file is in the same directory. Still doesn't work; [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eFih.png), and [the html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKNFF.png). I tried moving the img.jpg to the templates/images directory and try `<img src="images/img.jpg" height="400" width="374">` within the html file but that didn't work either.

**b-)** It could be a typo, but from the images up there that shouldn't be the case either.

**c-)** Files could be corrupted, I can open the image with browsers and tried using different images too.

**d-)** Img could be restricted, but that is not the case [either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFD5p.png). I think.

Trying to fix this for two days now, thought for some reason usage of extend or block might cause some problems and tried without them, still no good. and as I said its only a problem with local files. Can use files with direct link.

Comment: Does your network log show a request to the correct image path? If you visit that path in the browser can you see the image?

Comment: Files being in the same directory, doesn't mean they will be served on the same URL path. Use proper absolute paths.

Comment: I checked the error logs, '2022-07-15 14:50:51,122: Not Found: /tr/utku.jpg' and similar errors were there. host/tr/utku.jpg or other image path wont show the image only a Not Found error page.

Comment: When I locally hosted the site i used their literal paths too, example: C:\Users\USER\diretories\templates\img.jpg. Do you mean like this?

Comment: Do you even know under what URLs are those images served?

Comment: Comment made by lucutzu33 made it work, but I don't know under what URLs were the images served. In the error log i get the not found error, Not Found: /utku.jpg and i assumed the URL would be 'domain/utku.jpg'. Thank you @gre_gor and mousetail btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### settings.py

```
# add this to your settings.py
import os

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Then create a folder named `static` inside your app's folder. Then create another folder with the same name as your app inside that `static` folder.

The resulting structure should be: `your_project_name/your_app_name/static/your_app_name/`

You can also create a folder named `images` inside that last folder.

The resulting structure should be: `your_project_name/your_app_name/static/your_app_name/images/`

Place your image (let's call it `my_image.jpg`) insite that `images` folder.

Now in your template you can use the `static` tag:

```
{% load static %}
...
<img src="{% static 'your_app_name/images/my_image.jpg' %}" alt="">
```

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: This worked, huge thanks! I already had a static directory and had those configurations in the settings.py file. Adding  the image folder to the static directory and loading static within the html file made it work. Thanks again!

Comment: in reality, static folder is for js/css  and really static images, like favicon for admin panel. If you has a user defined images - they should be in media folder.

Answer (score -1):

django serve html with views:

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'my.html'
```

for template in Django exists template settings.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-TEMPLATES
templates should be in special folder.

Images Django takes from media or static settings.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#media-root
images should be in special folder.

Try configuring your project accordingly for Django-Project.